# Failed to invoke procedure `netscan.find_communities`: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.neo4j.graphdb.Result org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDataba

Tags: neo4j

i found syntax for community detection from https://github.com/vitorhorta/netscan-neo4j
and I found this syntax
**CALL netscan.find_communities('Person','LIKES', 'id','weight', 'INCOMING', true, 0.5, 5, 1);**

When i tried to run this algorithm there's is a problem like this:

**Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed**

**Failed to invoke procedure netscan.find_communities: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.neo4j.graphdb.Result org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService.execute(java.lang.String)'**

I have installed plugin netscan-1.0.0 and put it on plugins folder on neo4j and that problem always appearing.
Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

The pom of that plugin shows it was built for Neo4j 3.1.1 https://github.com/vitorhorta/netscan-neo4j/blob/master/pom.xml#L15 , you have to run a Neo4j instance of the same version.

If you want to do community detection, the GDS (Graph Datascience Library) is covering such algorithm : https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/community/

Comment: Do yo know where i can download neo4j 3.1.1 version? I cant find website or link to download 3.1.1 version